# Convert a number into "bracket" numerals

Tags: code-golf, number, base-conversion

"Bracket" numerals are a type of 'numerals' I made up once, and thought would be a nice challenge here. Basically, you convert the input number into base 6, and then transliterate the `012345` respectively with `()[]{}`<sup>*†*</sup>, so every `0` becomes `(`, every `1` becomes `)`, etc.
You don't have to use `()[]{}` per se. As long as you specify what characters you use, you can use any other characters (except for digits, otherwise *just* converting to base-6 would have been enough!)

Since this is tagged [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the score is in bytes, where the least amount of bytes wins.

A few examples: 6 = `)(`. 100200 = `[(})}[(`. 44790 = `}{][)(`.

Here is some lengthy JavaScript code which accomplishes what I described above. Since it's a snippet (using variable `x`) instead of a function or full program, it isn't valid however:

```js
var [x,q,w] = [0,0,0];q = x.toString('6');w = q.replace(/0/g, '(');q = w.replace(/1/g, ')');w = q.replace(/2/g, '[');q = w.replace(/3/g, ']');w = q.replace(/4/g, '{');q = w.replace(/5/g, '}');console.log(q);
```

Yes, that is 207 bytes. You probably can do better! I will accept an answer on June 1st, 2019, but you can continue to post answers afterwards of course.

[Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call. So you aren't allowed to have a `var x` like I did in my example JavaScript snippet.
[Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

Comment: The contest ended 2 weeks ago? Can you give some sample inputs/outputs and test cases?

Comment: Penalties and bonuses generally don't make challenges more fun. That said, I think you intended to make using a variable as input penalised but it actually gives an unbeatable score of zero? I'd recommend just removing them but if you want to keep them then that definitely needs to change.

Comment: _As long as you specify what characters you use, you don't need to use brackets_: so we can just convert to base 6?

Comment: I would actually remove the 2nd "bonus" entirely rather than turning it into a penalty. Languages that *can* take dynamic input almost always will, be it from args, stdin, or function params, and it's unfair to penalize languages that *can't* take dynamic input

Comment: Do we need to support \$n=0\$?

Comment: I disagree that this is unclear. It may be a bad challenge that has a lot of loopholes that can be downvoted, but that doesn't make it unclear.

Comment: I've edited your challenge to make it more in line with other challenges. If you see anything incorrect after my edit, feel free to change it again. I've also added a rule that digits are disallowed completely in your characters of choice, which automatically disqualifies simply converting to base-6.

Comment: If you choose to keep @KevinCruijssen's changes then be sure to inform all existing solutions that simply converting to base-6 is no longer permitted. (I'll hold off on updating my own solution until you do so).

Comment: Whether or not `0` needs to be handled as input still needs to be addressed. Also, can we use unprintable characters in the replacement?

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 bytes

Uses `[objec`.

```
s6îM
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=czbuTQ&input=OA)

### Alternative 4 bytes

Uses the (unprintable) characters at codepoints `1-6`.

```
s6õd
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=czb1ZA&input=OAotUQ)

Or, if that's not allowed:

#### 5 bytes

Using `!"#$%&`.

```
s6õdH
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=czb1ZEg&input=OA)

Or, also (using `wander`):

```
s`æ`â
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=c2DmYOI&input=OA)

If I can figure out a 6 letter word that Shoco can compress to a single character then that last one can be golfed to 3 bytes.

Comment: `;sF¯6` also works for 5

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance, that's different enough to post yourself. I was deliberately avoiding the alt. variables 'cause having to add 25% to my score with `;` was annoying me!

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>11</s> <s>10</s> <s>5</s> 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

All three programs below will return a list of characters instead of a joined string.

```
žOÅв
```

Uses `aeiouy` instead of `()[]{}` for `0123456` respectively.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0dPswqbDK/7/NzQyNgEA)

---

Answers which actually use `()[]{}`:

**<s>11 10</s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**:

```
žu„<>мÅв
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L7SRw3zbOwu7DncemHT//@GRsYmAA)

**8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) alternative by *@Grimy***:

```
…([{º{Åв
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMyjejqQ7uqD7de2PT/v6GRsQkA)

**Explanation:**

```python
žO        # Push string builtin "aeiouy"
  Åв      # Convert the (implicit) input to this custom base-"aeiouy"
          # (which is output implicitly as result)

žu        # Push string builtin "()<>[]{}"
  „<>м    # Remove the "<>" from this string: "()[]{}"
      Åв  # Convert the (implicit) input to this custom base-"()[]{}"
          # (which is output implicitly as result)

…([{      # Push string "([{"
    º     # Mirror it vertically to "([{}])"
     {    # Sort the characters in the string: "()[]{}"
      Åв  # Convert the (implicit) input to this custom base-"()[]{}"
          # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: There's a builtin which pushes `()<>[]{}`? Just why?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance it could be because `()<>[]{}` are all the typeable "bracket" characters on your keyboard i.e. all of them are used to enclose something. Maybe the purpose is so you can do what @KevinCruijssen did here and crop out some characters so you have some else.

Comment: Alternative 8-byter using `()[]{}`: `…({[º{Åв`. (Or drop the `{` for a 7 byter using the same characters but in a different order).

Comment: @Grimy Ah, I indeed tried with both `…({[` and `º` as well to see if I could make something shorter, but ended up at 10 bytes. Didn't realize the sort would put them in the desired `()[]{}` order. :)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>36</s>  34 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Shaggy*

Character set: `[`,`o`,`b`,`j`,`e` and `c`.

```javascript
f=n=>(n>5?f(n/6|0):'')+({}+0)[n%6]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY2xDsIgFEV3v4LFAOFRoRViNODkVzQdSC1V0zxMa1zUb0c6nJOTu9xHeIeln@/Pl8R0HXKODp1n6M05MtzZr@JHSrlgn59QvMWt7fKpVaChhgb2YMCCVtCsViulD7o23aaKab6E/saQOE/6hEuahmpKYxkEoURKXyxIueGc5z8)

Comment: [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##FY2xDsIgFEV3v4LFAOFRoRViNODkVzQdSC1V0zxMa1zUb0c6nJOTu9xHeIeln@/Pl8R0HXKODp1n6M05MtzZr@JHSrlgn59QvMWt7fKpVaChhgb2YMCCVtCsViulD7o23aaKab6E/saQOE/6hEuahmpKYxkEoURKXyxIueGc5z8), using alternative characters.

Comment: So you saved -28 bytes? I think you replaced the wrong digit.

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>65</s> <s>63</s> 60 bytes

Using STDIN and not command line arguments:

```bash
while read n;do echo "obase=6;$n"|bc|tr 012345 '()[]{}';done
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzwjMydVoSg1MUUhzzolXyE1OSNfQSk/KbE41dbMWiVPqSYpWUG3sKakSMHA0MjYxFRBXUMzOra6Vh2oOi/1/38DLkMuUy4zLkMgwwCMDbiMLQyNTAE)

Comment: Nice one. You may try `dc`, is often shorter than `bc`: `while read n;do dc<<<6o$n\ p|tr 012345 '()[]{}';done`.

Comment: Ahh!  Don't use dc very much -- cannot stand RP notation :-), reminds me of very old steam powered calculators.  Thanks for the tip mind.  And yes, I could have removed the first pair of ' ' but habit means I left them in.

Comment: Rejected post approved by answerer (me) as I forgot to login when I amended it.  Removed 3 bytes by deleting superfluous 'bc' option.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
⍘Ｎ()[]{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMpsTg1uATITNfwzCsoLfErzU1KLdLQ1FFQ0tCMjq2uVdLUtP7/38TE3NLgv25ZDgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 Ｎ          Input as a number
⍘           Base convert using specified characters
  ()[]{}    Literal string of required characters
```

5 bytes using the letters `a-f` (or `A-F` also works):

```
⍘Ｎ…β⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMpsTg1uATITNfwzCsoLfErzU1KLdLQ1FFwrkzOSXXOyC/QSNJRMNPU1LT@/9/ExNzS4L9uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 Ｎ      Input as a number
⍘       Base convert using
  … ⁶   First six characters of
   β    Lowercase alphabet
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 64 bytes

```
#~IntegerDigits~6/.Table[k->StringTake["()[]{}",{k+1}],{k,0,5}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X7nOM68kNT21yCUzPbOkuM5MXy8kMSknNTpb1y64pCgzLz0kMTs1WklDMzq2ulZJpzpb27A2FkjpGOiY1saq/Q8AqilRiFZSsrFLjzYzM4uN/f8fAA)

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P7ikKDMvPSCxqCRaSUMzOra6VknHUFu5zjOvJDU9tcglMz2zpLjOLFbtfwBQYYlCtJKSjV16tJmZWWzs//8A "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 53 bytes

```php
<?=strtr(base_convert($argn,10,6),'012345','()[]{}');
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwMWlkliUnqdgq2BoYGBgzcVlbweUsC0uKSop0khKLE6NT87PK0stKtEAq9MxNNAx09RRNzA0MjYxVddR19CMjq2uVde0/v8fAA)

I'll be honest, I still don't understand the bonus, but here's a PHP version.

Comment: Huh.. How are you able to post an answer when it's closed as unclear for more than an hour?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, you can still post from the SE app after a question has been closed if you loaded it before it was closed or had a draft saved.

Comment: @kevincruijssen, I just posted this from the web version. Possibly I hadn't refreshed the page since the question was closed and it doesn't check for it. Smells like a SE bug report!

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 47 bytes

```cs
n=>m=>{do m[0]+="()[]{}"[n%6];while((n/=6)>0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY2xCsIwFEVn@xUhICS0Yrp0MH0BF0Ho7lA7xVYf2Fdon3QI@fYacbp3OOdevxz8gtvlQ75G4uLsGSeqrw0uXC88Iz2dcwNsBG4EFx6TGFvT5SCVbrsQZUv7qrPrC9@9UnSESjujbdxs9rfbjoH6NbFSRpsN06zSj0AwFmsoTYo81yJkO067IKXNdoNCrVindpuR@wapVzKYeOeTCGWUBRY/OAFx@wI)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ṃØỵ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//4bmDw5jhu7X/MTAwxbs74oCcIC0gPiDigJ07w4fGsuKCrFn//w)

Uses ‘aeiouy’ for ‘01235’.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 13 bytes

```apl
'()[]{}'⊇⍨6∘⊤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/9U1NKNjq2vVH3W1P@pdYfaoY8ajriX/04Byj3r7IMq6mg@tN37UNhHICw5yBpIhHp7B/1OASgxN7Q0NDAy4HvWuStE5tCLt0IoUAA)

Pretty straightforward tacit function. Test cases used are 15 randomly selected integers between 0 and 999.

Uses `⎕IO←0`.

Thanks to @Adám for 2 bytes

#### How:

```apl
'()[]{}'⊇⍨6∘⊤ ⍝ Tacit function
          6∘⊤ ⍝ Convert input to base 6
        ⊇     ⍝ Index the right argument with the indices in the left argument
         ⍨    ⍝ With arguments swapped
'()[]{}'      ⍝ Character vector
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 28 bytes

Uses `abcdef` in place of `012345`.

```ruby
->x{x.to_s(6).tr'0-5','a-f'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9euorpCryQ/vljDTFOvpEjdQNdUXUc9UTdNvfZ/QWlJsUJatEo8SEFm7H9DCy5LSy7Df/kFJZn5ecX/dfMA)